# How can I connect SQL Server with ORM Doctrine on my symfony project?

Tags: sql-server, symfony, orm, doctrine

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 8889
        user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
        password: '%env(DATABASE_PWD)%'
        dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
     #   url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use driver `pdo_sqlsrv` or `sqlsrv`, not `pdo_mysql`.

([See doctrine configuration documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)).

> pdo_sqlsrv: A Microsoft SQL Server driver that uses pdo_sqlsrv PDO

> sqlsrv: A Microsoft SQL Server driver that uses the sqlsrv PHP
> extension.

Available configuration for `pdo_sqlsrv`/`sqlsrv` are:

```
user (string): Username to use when connecting to the database.
password (string): Password to use when connecting to the database.
host (string): Hostname of the database to connect to.
port (integer): Port of the database to connect to.
dbname (string): Name of the database/schema to connect to.
```

The documentation says that:

> The following drivers support automatic database platform detection
> out of the box without any extra configuration required:
>
> ```
> pdo_mysql
> mysqli
> pdo_pgsql
> pdo_sqlsrv
> sqlsrv
> ```

So you dont need to specify `server_version`.

You would have:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlsrv'
        charset: utf8mb4
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 8889
        user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
        password: '%env(DATABASE_PWD)%'
        dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
     #   url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```